# Can I define my own constructor for the System.Object type?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, code-injection

How can I define my own constructor for the System.Object type, such that when any `byref` type gets initialized, it calls my custom constructor? Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit:
After I read part of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx, there might be a way to do it. Is it possible to just replace method pointer somewhere in method table?

Comment: No, you can not monkey-patch .NET. Why are you trying to?

Comment: Love "monkey-patch". lol

Comment: @Simon it is the term for the scenario: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Comment: @Marc Oh I know, I just love the term lol.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes. It may be difficult to find because of how specific it is, but the subject matter is sure to be the question of others somewhat new to the language.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to override a class's (or every class)'s constructor(s).  You can inherit from a particular class if it isn't sealed, and add additional logic to that class's constructor.  You could also use a factory method.  Another option you could look at would be to use [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/), or some other proxy library.